# Can nokogiri handle css selector with optional tags?

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri

Is it possible to define a css selector in nokogiri with two optional tags?

As a (not working) example:

```
  document.css('/hello-world [greeting|gruss]').each{|g| 
    ...
  }
```

I would like to get all 'greeting' and 'gruss'-tags in the correct order.

In a complete minimal not working example:

```
XML = <<-XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="hello.xsl"?>
<hello-world>   
  <greeting>Hello, World!</greeting>
  <gruss>Hallo, Welt!</gruss>
</hello-world>
XML

require 'nokogiri'

document = Nokogiri::XML(XML)
[
#This two are working, but it is in two different loops:
  '/hello-world greeting',
  '/hello-world gruss',
#This does not work:
  '/hello-world [greeting|gruss]',  #Does not work
].each{|css_path|
  puts "Scan css path '%s':" % css_path
  document.css(css_path).each{|g| puts "  Found: %s" % g.content }
}
```

The result is:

```
Scan css path '/hello-world greeting':
  Found: Hello, World!
Scan css path '/hello-world gruss':
  Found: Hallo, Welt!
Scan css path '/hello-world [greeting|gruss]':
```

The last css-elements ends with a Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError. Is there a possibility to get all elements in the two tags with one css-selector?

Comment: One solution I found: Use `'./hello-world//greeting|./hello-world//gruss'` as a xpath.. But I look for a solution with css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS you just use a comma to select multiple nodes:

```
document.css 'greeting, gruss'
```

If you want to be more specific you need to repeat the entire selector:

```
document.css 'hello-world greeting, hello-world gruss'
```

There’s no way to shorten this currently (something like the [`any` psuedo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any) could work, but isn’t available in Nokogiri).

In XPath you could do something like

```
document.xpath '//hello-world//*[name() = "greeting" or name() = "gruss"]'
```

which isn’t any shorter but means you avoid repeating the first part of the query.

You could also perhaps look at creating a custom function if this is something you plan to do a lot, which could be used from CSS or XPath.